# How do I randomly select an item from a list in Jython using a while loop?

Tags: list, random, while-loop, jython

I need to make something that randomly picks something from a list randomly, but the catch is that it has to be with a while loop. I honestly am not sure where to start. I was thinking something with a counter? Maybe I am completely wrong. I am not good at this.

```
x = ["Bob", "Jim", "Billy", "OtherRandomName"]
counter = 0
while counter < x:
x = x + randrange(1, 5)
x = x + 1
```

I was thinking something like that, but I am probably way off. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider including an [CVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to show some random choice in a `while` loop then you can use such code:

```
import random

x = ["Bob", "Jim", "Billy", "OtherRandomName"]
max_counter = 10
counter = 0
while counter < max_counter:
    counter += 1
    print('%d %s' % (counter, random.choice(x)))
```